# Why do MGI and WGS 84 data not line up in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, georeferencing, wgs84

When i reproject raster from MGI 6 zone to the WGS84 it makes a mistake (it is moved for 380 m )See example below:[image]

I know that the problem is in MGI 6 projection (it is not accurate),but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with MGI Zones but it looks like you have not provided your data frame with the **Transformation** to use between the datum of the layer which appears incorrect and the datum of the data frame.

To correct this:

1. Open the **Data Frame Properties** to the **Coordinate Systems** tab and click the **Transformations** button
2. Make sure that the **Convert from:** is set to the datum of the layer which appears incorrect
3. Do not change the **Into:** setting
4. Under **Using:** choose a transformation - there can be some science to this choice but for now just choose the first one offered
5. Click **OK** twice to apply the changes

I expect your layers will now line up.

If it does not, then I would recommend editing your Question to provide more details about the country this data comes from, and what your "reproject raster" steps including the input coordinate system and parameters used were.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 7 parameter transformation:

1. Projections and Transformations/Create Custom Geographic Transformation
2. Input Geographic Coordinate System: MGI_Balkans_6
3. Output...: GCS_WGS_1984
4. Method: COORDINATE_FRAME
5. Parameters: 
   DX=546,70776
   DY=162,37348
   DZ=469,53683
   rX=-5,90560751
   rY=-2,07314165
   rZ=11,51062442
   dM=-4,45886242